# How can Wednesday cut her brother's arm and nothing happened?

Tags: addams-family

In the movie *The Addams Family*, Wednesday cut off her brother Pugsley's arm, but it doesn't seem like it had any lasting consequences.

Is there any official explanation about how the arm got reattached?

They did many other things too that don't make sense.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a fake arm (or at least, it wasn't his arm).

I think the implication is that it was in the package Fester gave them. The only mention in the script:

> In a final vengeful moment, Wednesday HACKS AT PUGSLEY'S
> LEFT ARM, CUTTING IT OFF, SENDING A GUSHER OF BLOOD OUT
> OF HIS STUMP. THE ARM DROPS TO THE STAGE AND BOUNCES OFF,
> LANDING IN JUDGE WOMACK'S LAP.

You could interpret it as cutting his actual arm off, and then someone sewed it back on. The Addams films are full of implied maimings and things that would kill someone, but have no effect. Especially to Pugsly and Fester.

But I think the more obvious answer is they went beyond expectations in stage effects for a school play (and they already did with the choice of Hamlet).

Comment: so nothing officials either. It can be anything

Comment: There's nothing useful in the novelisation; https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCQTv.png

Comment: You'd have to explain the sustained, high-pressure, *aerated* spray of blood as well, if Pugsley's arm had actually been cut off. (At the very least, the blood would come in spurts as the heart beats, instead of acting like a garden hose.)

Comment: Nothing useful in the Movie Storybook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9riOW.png

Comment: @chepner which is another reason to go for "fake arm" and some pumps and tubing.

Comment: Yes, my point is that there's little reason to believe it's anything *other* than a fake arm.

Comment: @chepner technically, I think it's probably a real arm.

Comment: @OrangeDog Ah, yes :) I wonder whose?